How can I fix a "black background" when using XQuartz on an Apple Silicon Mac?
When attempting to use applications through XQuartz, such as PyCharm on a remote Linux machine via NoMachine, large numbers of background elements appear "black" on the screen, and if you screenshot them, you find that they are actually transparent.
This can end up with a screen that looks like this:

What can I do to get these applications rendering correctly?

This issue in the XQuartz tracker covers the problem.
The solution that appears to work for the most people, myself included, is to turn off the render extension, which can be done by running this in a shell:
defaults write org.xquartz.X11 enable_render_extension 0


If this doesn't work, or work well enough, you may have to set your JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in either the starting shell script for the java app, or as an env var if you're ssh'd on terminal and starting it manually:
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dsun.java2d.xrender=false -Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false -Dremote.x11.workaround=false -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine -Djava2d.font.loadFontConf=true'

